# Check if an companion object from another class is initialized before using it

Tags: android, kotlin, initialization, retrofit, okhttp

I'm initializing my retrofit client in Base Application android class, and in MainActivity I'm using it to call api.
Sometimes, the api call starts before Base class could initialize my retrofit client and it crashes the app.
How do I check in MainActivity before making api call that if apiInterface client is initialized or not before making the rest api call?

I know that we can do this to check initialization for lateinit variables in a class.

```
::variable.isInitialized
```

But It's not working in this case as I access the static object like this BaseApp.apiInterface
Here's my code:

**BaseApp.kt**

```
 class BaseApp : Application() {   
        companion object {     
            lateinit var apiInterfaceLogin: ApiInterface
            lateinit var apiInterface: ApiInterface   
            lateinit var okHttpClient: OkHttpClient.Builder
        }
       
     override fun onCreate() {
            super.onCreate()
            fetchPrefs()
            initData()
        }
    
     private fun initData() {           
     val interceptor = Interceptor { chain ->
                    val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("app-token", Constants.APP_TOKEN)
                        .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
                        .build()
                    chain.proceed(newRequest)
                }
                okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                okHttpClient.interceptors().add(interceptor)
                val client = okHttpClient.build()
    
                val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(ApiInterface.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .build()
                apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
        }  
    }
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    companion object {
        
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        checkShifts()  
    }

    private fun checkShifts() {
        val checkShiftsApiCall = BaseApp.apiInterface.startRun(BaseApp.userId)
        checkShiftsApiCall.enqueue(object : Callback<MyAvailableShiftsResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<MyAvailableShiftsResponse>, response: Response<MyAvailableShiftsResponse>) {
               
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<MyAvailableShiftsResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a misuse of `lateinit` to publicly expose a property with it that might possibly not be initialized by the time it is accessed. If other classes have to check if it’s initialized before using it, it might as well be nullable so you can take advantage of all the operators and functions that deal with nullability in a cleaner, safer way. Alternatively you could expose a Deferred property so other classes can simply retrieve and `await()` it in a coroutine so it’s safe and never null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose it using additional property in `BaseApp` companion:

```kotlin
val isApiInterfaceInitialized get() = ::apiInterface.isInitialized
```

As a side note, you can access properties of companion objects, but you need to reference them explicitly, for example:

```kotlin
BaseApp.Companion::apiInterface
```

Still, accessing `isInitialized` is disallowed from outside the object as this is considered implementation details that `apiInterface` is `lateinit`.

Also, the main use case of `lateinit` is when we are sure that we initialize it before the first use. If you need to always/often check it before use or you use it outside the object, then regular nullable property may be a better choice.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. val isApiInterfaceInitialized get() = ::apiInterface.isInitialized

Comment: Also, it is initialized and in most cases it works fine, but sometimes a few ms delay in apiclient getting initialzed and it causes a crash and it gets intialized after. Do you know an alternative for this? If I want just one apiClient and I initialize it only once in base class, then how could i prevent the same issue with an object that's outside the class.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure why does it happen in the first place. It seems `BaseApp.onCreate()` can't finish without first initializing `apiInterface` and I believe activities and other components always wait for application to initialize. Are you sure you don't access `apiInterface` from places like e.g. constructors, other companion objects, etc.?

Comment: I'm only accessing it on login page, from a setOnclicklistener that is in onCreate. BaseApp.isApiInterfaceLoginInitialized is giving false now, It worked once but after I logged out and tried again, this gives false every time, I was checking for this to be true and only then Login button should work and api should call. but since this is false, it's stuck at this line. I think I'll have to remove this line. Any idea if I'm missing anything?

Comment: Where is `apiInterfaceLogin` initialized? Because earlier you were talking about `apiInterface`, but now it is `apiInterfaceLogin`. Are you sure you didn't make a mistake due to similarity in naming and possibly some copy & paste? For example, you initialize `apiInterface` twice instead of `apiInterfaceLogin`.

Comment: it's two apinterface objects that i'm initializing in base class and have to use them in another class the same way. i only shared code for one bcz the process is same. I used the code you shared for both, but it returns false for both. i'll make an edit in the question

Comment: Sorry, but this code just should work. I believe there must be some small mistake somewhere. For example `BaseApp` is not registered as the application class. Or it throws an exception when initializing. Try adding some logs before and after `apiInterface = ` and `apiInterfaceLogin = ` to make sure it is invoked and to see whether it happens before or after you use these props.